# How to call an endpoint of one container from another flask container running on different ports in docker compose?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose, docker-network

I am trying to implement 3 flask docker containers using docker-compose. I'm running each flask app on a different port `127.0.0.1:5000`,`127.0.0.1:5001`,`127.0.0.1:5002`. I've mentioned the containers in `docker-compose.yml` file. The `docker-compose` is creating a default network.

But when I try to access `5001 container's` flask endpoint from `5000 container's` code like

`requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5001/endpoint')`, It is throwing following error.

> HTTPConnectionPool(host=\'0.0.0.0\', port=5001): Max retries exceeded
>   with url (Caused by NewConnectionError

Does anyone know why I'm getting this.

Comment: user service names instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I'm sorry. Relatively new to flask and docker containers. can you please point me in a direction.

Comment: in compose , you use service names for each flask container, use them

Comment: Whoa. That worked like a charm. Used the `servicename:5001`. Thank you so much. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are attempting to connect to localhost within the docker container itself, i.e. the traffic stays within that docker container.

What you want to do instead is to connect to your other container by its hostname. Within the context of the network managed by docker/docker-compose that is just the name of the docker container. E.g. for a container `foo` you can connect over HTTP to port 5001 using `http://foo:5001/` inside your container.